# Getting historical imagery of Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, jquery

I want to show historical images of google map of particular location and images will change when we click previous next button according to its published date ?

Answer (score 2):

That feature is not available on Maps. You can do it easily in Google Earth. Click the "clock" icon at the top of the window and you'll see a time slider. Next and previous buttons will walk through the dates of the imagery -- not the publication date, but the date the image was acquired.

Comment: I believe the historical street view imagery is only available in Maps.